# How can I login to a website using Java and stay logged in?

Tags: java, authentication, apache-commons, urlconnection

So what i am trying to do is log into a a web app that is used by our company, I need to download multiple graphs(45 to be exact) I have a program that will do this exactly how i want it to, However the way my code works it has to log in each time. I'm not sure if this is a problem( Might look suspicious to the admin of the web app) or not but it seems a little inefficient. Ideally I would like to log into the site once and them move to whatever Urls I need to download the images. Any help you guys could offer would be great.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 45; i++) {
                URL url;
                if(i<10) {
                    url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:3333/website/image0"+i);

                }

                else{
                    url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:3333/website/image"+i);

                }
                String loginPassword = "usrName" + ":" + "PassWrd";
                String encoded = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(loginPassword.getBytes());
                URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);


                String destName = "C:\\Users\\Name\\Documents\\Report\\p"+i+".png";
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(destName);

                byte[] b = new byte[2048];
                int length;

                while ((length = in.read(b)) != -1) {
                    os.write(b, 0, length);
                }

                in.close();
                os.close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will largely depend on the website you're trying to get the images off of. Most of the time, the website will use [Cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) to keep track of the fact that you're logged in.

Java provides a class specifically for this purpose to be used with [HttpUrlConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html): The [CookieHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/CookieHandler.html)

Using that class to set the default handler to a [CookieManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/CookieManager.html) will probably be enough for you to stay logged in. Something like this:

```
CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager(null, CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL));
// null for the CookieStore means CookieManager will use an in-memory implementation
// And CookiePolicy.ACCEPT_ALL means that this CookieHandler will accept
// all cookies
```

In case your website uses something else to identify its users, you will have to reverse engineer the process and implement it in your program. Generally though, everything that can be done with a browser can be done with Java as well so it should always be possible.

Edit: After writing this whole thing I just realized that you're website uses HTTP Authentication. In this case Cookies won't actually help, since you have reauthorize every request anyway. HTTP does not have a state by itself, so the server won't remember at all that you were already logged in. If this is the only way that a user can get access to those images then there will be nothing suspicious about it, since a browser has to resend the username and the password with every request as well.

I would recommend saving the encoded String somewhere just to not have it being regenerated every time.

I'll still leave the Cookie thing up, since there might still be some use for it in case the authentication mechanisms are different.